# Import module failed even though installed

Tags: python, python-3.x

i have a couple of different questions regarding importing modules and another non-related syntax question.
So, i'm using a module called netmiko to automate networking scripts, this isn't a networking question but a python one, i create the scripts in Pycharm and then run them but when i tried to do one last night for the first time using Netmiko it's coming up with an import module failed exception which is confusing me because i've installed it using "pip install netmiko" and i saw it install AND if i do "import netmiko" using the command line on Windows then it works as well with no exceptions. So i've been building the scripts in Pycharm but having to copy/paste them into then cli which isn't great. Does anybody know what the issue may be here?

The second question is just a general syntax question. I've seen "+=" used when using the same variable names in Python (mainly used in netmiko scripts but i assume it's obviously used in other Python scripts to) such as:

```
output = net_connect.send_command(cmd, expect_string=r'Destination filename')
output += net_connect.send_command('\n', expect_string=r'#')
```

....the rest of the script isn't import, but i'm wondering what the "+=" is actually doing here because to me it seems no different than doing:

```
output = net_connect.send_command(cmd, expect_string=r'Destination filename')
output = net_connect.send_command('\n', expect_string=r'#')
```

Can anyone shed some light on this as well?

Thanks as usual everyone!!

Comment: Hi Michael, If you have two question please post them separately as users can then find them and answer them singularly with more confidence.
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts

Comment: `x += y` is equivalent to `x = x + y`.  It is very different from `x = y`.